# Issues attempting to align text inside of list containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have a row of four li containers with H3 text inside of each one. I want the text centered both vertically and horizontally but can only get it vertically. Tried numerous times with vertical-align: middle; but no luck. Here's what I'm using.

HTML:

```
<ul class="products oceanwp-row clr grid shop-variety">
    <li style="background-image: url( http://flowerlinkla.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/bkg-garden-rose.jpg ) !important;" class="shop-variety product col span_1_of_4"><div class="shop-content"><h3>Garden Rose</h3></div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.shop-variety.product.col.span_1_of_4 {
    height: 285px;
    width: 24%;
    margin: 24px .5%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Should mention I tried display: flex as well. No luck.

http://flowerlinkla.com/staging/shop/

Comment: You got it horizontally centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you try `display: flex`, it needs some other properties like [**`justify-content`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [**`align-items`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

```css
.shop-variety.product.col.span_1_of_4 {
  /* Remove */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;

  /* Add */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That explain why it wasn't working. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @manoj-kumar is perfect.
Just to clarify, **justify-content** aligns children elements on the main axis.
For example, if you are orienting your flex horizontally (`flex-direction: row` - that's the default value), `justify-content: center` will center children elements horizontally.

On the other hand, **align-items** will align it on the secondary axis. If you are orienting your flex vertically (`flex-direction: column`), `align-items: center` will center children elements horizontally and `justify-content: center` will center children elements vertically.

Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/annabranco/pen/JwXpzr?editors=1100) to make it visually more clear. ;)

And here you can read all about Flexbox properties.
[https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/]

I hope it helps.